# Xss Config for data attributes

Tags: java, aem, xss, antisamy

How to configure XSS-protection config.xml for data-* attributes. It is getting filtered. So far we are adding manually for each data-* attributes. Is there any way to have a generic fix?

For eg if we have `<img data-src="url"/>` we are adding like below.

```
<tag action="validate" name="img">
            <attribute name="data-src" onInvalid="removeTag">
                <regexp-list>
                    <regexp name="onsiteURL"/>
                    <regexp name="offsiteURL"/>
                </regexp-list>
            </attribute>
</tag>
```

Instead of this, any fix could provide in common? So that it will allow all data attributes?